# PHP: how to get custom date PHP 5.1.6

Tags: php

I have a code in php 5.1.6

which is:

```
$tz = date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tokyo");
$date = date('2016-11-24 07:27:00 +00');
$date = date_default_timezone_get($tz);
$currentDate = date('F d, Y H:i');
```

I keep getting the current time on my output

> November 24, 2016 16:09

How can I get

> November 24, 2016 19:27

Thank you

Comment: can you just try to convert $date to milliseconds like this $currentDate = date('F d, Y H:i', strtotime($date));

Comment: You need to update your server to a supported version of PHP. 5.1.6 is over ten years old (released August 2006).

Comment: I have added a code which will work with your code.

Comment: `date('F d, Y H:i', strtotime('2016-11-24 07:27:00 +00'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code below should help you:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$datetime = new DateTime('2016-11-24 07:27:00');
$tokyo_time = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Tokyo');
$datetime->setTimezone($tokyo_time);
echo $datetime->format('F d, Y H:i');
```

If you want to add 3 hours you can use code below:

```
$datetime->add(new DateInterval('PT3H'));
```

So your code could look like follows:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$datetime = new DateTime('2016-11-24 07:27:00');
$tokyo_time = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Tokyo');
$datetime->setTimezone($tokyo_time);
echo $datetime->format('F d, Y H:i');
$datetime->add(new DateInterval('PT3H'));
```

More informations can be found in manuals below:

- [PHP: DateTime::add](http://php.net/manual/pl/datetime.add.php)
- [PHP: DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [PHP: DateTimeZone](http://php.net/manual/pl/class.datetimezone.php)

**PHP 5.1.6**

If it doesnt work add those lines in your code:

```
$newdate = date('F d, Y H:i', strtotime($date.' + 3 hours'));
echo $newdate;
```

And your code would look as follows:

```
$tz = date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tokyo");
$date = date('2016-11-24 07:27:00 +00');
$date = date_default_timezone_get($tz);
$currentDate = date('F d, Y H:i');
$newdate = date('F d, Y H:i', strtotime($date.' + 3 hours'));
echo $newdate;
```

More about used method you can read in [PHP:strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Hello @Karol . I have this code before . It is working on version 5.3 . but it doesn't work on PHP 5.1.6

Comment: Welcome :) Glad could help